# Django add foreign key fields to generic.CreateView

Tags: django

Thanks in advance,  I'm learning django and making a poll project, what I want to achieve is make the user Create a question + add some answers choices, so I have a Question class based view and a Choice one

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField("Question", max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        "date de publication", default=timezone.now)
    popularity = models.IntegerField("popularité", default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text




class Choice(models.Model):
    question_lie = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, to_field="id", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

My CreateView :

```
class CreatePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ["question_text"]
    template_name = "polls/create_poll.html"
    success_url = "/polls"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

actually the user can just provide a question without answers, in the admin part I manage to do it like that :

```
class ChoiceInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 1

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    inlines = [ChoiceInLine]
```

Is there a similar way ? Thanks for reading

EDIT : I've found django-extra-view which mimic the admin way to do it, but is there a native way to do it ?

Comment: It's working fine with django-extra-views but I'm still curious on how to do it natively

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory) to achieve the same effects as the Django admin